# How to add Pull-to-refresh on UIView (not a UITableView, UICollectionView, UIScrollView)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

So I'm pretty new to iOS development, and want to add the pull-to-refresh behavior to the UIView. Is that possible? If so, how to implement it?

I see that there're a couple of examples of showing UIRefreshControl for UITableView, UIScrollView, and UICollectionView. [ex1](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/)

Is it possible to have the pull-to-refresh behavior for UIView only?

Comment: Do it through the view controller where a guy you so-call 'UIView' belongs.

Comment: You could add a gesture to your UIView to support 'pull' action, and add the "refresh" operation for the action. Actually the gesture will not work naturally as the UIScrollView does

Comment: @ElTomato, any examples that I can take a look to do it through view controller?

Comment: Sorry...  I don't think that's possible without `UIScrollView` or one of its cousins.

Comment: *"... want to add the pull-to-refresh behavior to the UIView."* -- When you say that, do you mean you want the UI to show your view being "pulled down" ... the spinner showing ... then the view bouncing back up? If so, is there a reason you don't want to put it in a scroll view?

Comment: @DonMag, ".. want the UI to show your view being "pulled down" ... the spinner showing ... then the view bouncing back up?" Yes! I'm working in a view controller, which other controllers built on top. I don't have UIScrollView available, only UIView. Is the alternative to create another UIScrollView on top of the UIView? What's the difference between UIview and UIScrollView (other than one's scrollable)? Is there any adverse affects that I should be aware if I replace UIView with UIScrollView? Thanks!

Comment: @jen007 - embedding your current view in a scroll view (with built-in refresh control functionality) should be very straight-forward. Perhaps if you edit your question with an example of your layout, and showing which view needs a "pull-to-refresh" feature, we can give you a bit more help.

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView` does have a build in refresh control, you may use a `uiscrollview` and pin it in the `view` of your view controller. This way you would be able to use the default build in `uirefreshcontrol`.

If you don't want to use the build in refresh control, then you would have to use pan gesture and would have to manually implement all the functionality, but it is not wise to reinvent the wheel.